# Chrome zooms in on navigation

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, mobile-chrome

I have a responsive layout that works great in mobile safari (iOS), but on chrome (Android) a strange thing is happening: there is a vertical navigation and if i click on some link that is in not at the end of the navigation - chrome "opens" sort of a popup displaying a zoomed in version of the area i clicked on and allows me to choose more precisely which link to click.

- What is this behavior called?
- Is there a way to disable it from HTML/CSS ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your HTML markup, or even better a live example, at a guess I presume the `meta-tag` may need revising.

Comment: That is a native android behavior in later versions.  I'll try to find out what it's called

Comment: It's called "Enable link preview" Search for that here http://www.chromestory.com/chrome-for-android-a-mini-user-guide/

Comment: @ntgCleaner thanks, looks like that's the thing i'm looking for. Unfortunately, there's no such thing i settings, not to mention disabling it in HTML/CSS. There are suggestions to use viewport approach, but that didn't seem logical; still - tried it - didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, width=<your_width>, minimum-scale=1.0"></meta>
```

into the `<head>` section of your page.
You'll have to change  according to your layout: if your page should be rendered according to a certain layout/document dimension, you'll have to declare the explicit layout width (ie: width=1024).
If your layout should adapt to the device screen resolution, you'll have to set: 
`width=device-width`.

Also is important to stress that the accepted values for the `user-scalable` part are [0,1] for Android (from api level 16, if I'm not wrong) and [yes, no] for iOS.

This fixes the annoying popup issue on Android Chrome.